# How to create a generic Pagination Connections schema in GraphQL

Tags: typescript, pagination, graphql

Relatively new to GraphQL. I have a question around how to make the connections style of pagination reusable in schema.

eg.) If I have such a schema

```js
type SomeEdge {
    node: SomeNodeView // This can be different for different use cases.
}

type SomeConnection {
    metaInfo: MetaInfo
    edges: SomeEdge // this can be different for different use cases.
}
// But the overall structure remains the same.
```

Is there a way to handle this a bit generic in GraphQL?

This is the closest I have found so far searching online (https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/190)

I am using this with Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL does not have generic types -- there is no syntax in GraphQL that supports doing what you're trying to do.

If you're building your schema using SDL, you can use [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (assuming you're using plain strings and not `.graphql` files) or use a library like [graphql-s2s](https://github.com/nicolasdao/graphql-s2s) which lets you use non-standard syntax that's then compiled to standard SDL.

Alternatively, you can use a code-first library to build your schema. Most, like TypeGraphQL, have [support for creating generic types](https://typegraphql.com/docs/generic-types.html).